# Different results in Linux than in Windows C++

Tags: c++, linux

I've created my code in Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 and it compiles and runs fine. I've moved this over to Linux and it gives me a different result for the GPA output. The GPA's are coming as 0 and 6.95281e-310 instead of the 3.9 and 3.5.

Also wondering if there is a difference between the `strcmp` and `strncpy` in Linux since I had to add `#include <cstring>` in my student.h?

Is there something else I should be using instead of `strncpy` in Linux?

#### student.h

```
#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H

#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class Student
{
public:
    Student(const char initId[], double gpa);
    bool isLessThanByID(const Student& aStudent) const;
    bool isLessThanByGpa(const Student& aStudent) const;
    void print()const;
private:
    const static int MAX_CHAR = 100;
    char    id[MAX_CHAR];
    double  gpa;
};
#endif
```

#### student.cpp

```
#include "student.h"


//implement the required 3 functions here


Student::Student(const char initId[], double gpa) : gpa(gpa)
{
    // initialize a newly created student object with the passed in value
    strncpy(id, initId, Student::MAX_CHAR - 1);
    if (Student::MAX_CHAR > 0)
{
    id[Student::MAX_CHAR - 1] = '\0';
}


}

bool Student::isLessThanByID(const Student& aStudent) const
{
    //  compare the current student object with the passed in one by id.
    if (strcmp(id, aStudent.id) > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }


}

bool Student::isLessThanByGpa(const Student& aStudent) const
{
    // compare the current student object with the passed in one by gpa
    if (gpa < aStudent.gpa)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}

void Student::print() const
{
    cout << id << '\t' << gpa << endl;
}
```

#### app.cpp

```
#include "student.h"

int main()
{
    Student s1("G10", 3.9);
    Student s2("G20", 3.5);

    s1.print();
    s2.print();

    if(s1.isLessThanByID(s2))
    {
        cout << "about right!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "uhmm ..." << endl;
    }
    if(!s1.isLessThanByGpa(s2))
    {
        cout << "about right!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "uhmm ..." << endl;
    }

    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using character arrays instead of [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)?

Comment: Take a look at the verbiage in your question.  You say "Is there a difference between the strcmp and strncpy in Linux?" — which is trivally answered "Yes; one is a comparator and one is a copier".  So, what were you really asking?

Comment: Everything was given to me the way it is. The only part I had to do was implement the three functions (Student, isLessThanByID and isLessThanGpa). Before I can turn it in, it has to work in Linux which I can't get to work.

Comment: Notice how in the `Student` constructor `gpa` is both a member variable and a named constructor argument. Try renaming one of the two (probably the constructor parameter).

Comment: You say the output of the GPA is not what you expect it to be, but this have nothing to do with the strings. Please clarify your question.

Comment: I've added that part in as I didn't need to add #include <cstring> in windows but in Linux I did. didn't know if there was a huge difference or not.

Comment: Your `student.h` header should not contain `#include <iostream>` or `#include <cstring>` or (especially) `using namespace std;`.  None of those is necessary to use the header.  They may be needed (probably are needed) in the implementation code, but they are not needed in the header that's shown.

Comment: Are you confusing `strcmp()` and `strcpy()`?  Why would you think that a copying function and a comparison function are remotely similar to each other?  The chances are that you're running into undefined behaviour, probably caused by not null terminating your strings properly.

Comment: The confusion is more if there is a difference within Windows and Linux. The main reason why I am asking, the output in Windows in the above code is 
    G10     3.9
    G20     3.5
While in Linux the output is now on the GPA.
    G10     0
    G20     6.95263e-310
I am trying to understand the disconnect between the two systems. I also cannot rename GPA in any portion.

Answer (score 0):

strcmp compares strings http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/

strncpy copies them http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/

There IS a great diff really between them, in Linux and other systems as well.

Comment: I've added that part in as I didn't need to add #include <cstring> in windows but in Linux I did. didn't know if there was a huge difference or not. However the strncpy gives me different results in Linux than it does in Windows. That is the part that is stumping me.

Comment: If you have to include a new library for it, it simply could be totally another function. But as you have it now, I can't understand, what line are you talking about? What function is there in Linux and what was in Windows. What is the difference in results of this very line for what exactly input data?